# R0 is violated after function returns

Tags: function, arm, return-value

I am implementing a uart queue in s3c44b0x (ARM7TDMI), the uart0 ISR will enqueue the char while the main loop will dequeue the char. however, while dequeuing, the value (in R0) returned may be not the one dequeued from the queue, and I found R0 is violated after returning from the dequeue function (input 'v' cont., and test() is in the main loop):
wish for your help.

```
CHAR cliDequeue(void)
{
    CHAR bTmpCh;

    if (gwCliQSize == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    bTmpCh = gabCliQ[gwCliQTail];  /* char is enqueued in the Q in ISR */
    gwCliQTail++;
    gwCliQTail %= MAX_CLI_QUEUE_LEN;
    ASSERT(gwCliQSize > 0);
    gwCliQSize--;

    ASSERT(bTmpCh == 'v');   /* will not assert */
    //uartPutChar(bTmpCh);
    return bTmpCh;
}

void test(void)
{
    CHAR bTestCh;

    bTestCh = cliDequeue();


    if (bTestCh != 0)
    { 
        ASSERT(bTestCh == 'v');  /* assert here ! */
            uartPutChar(bTestCh);

    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't happen everytime, just sometimes, about 1 out of 10.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have enough information / context to answer definitively.  It would also be helpful if you posted the corresponding assembly code so that we could see how/when things are moved in & out of R0.  REgardless, a few things spring to mind immediately from your posted C code.

(0) Are the variables shared between interrupts & the main loop declared as `volatile`?

(1) 
 In `CliDequeue`, you're accessing an array which is shared with an ISR.  It appears to be a single reader / single writer construct, so that isn't automatically bad, but your housekeeping isn't airtight.

For example, one invariant you must be sure to satisfy is that the queue size & tail pointer are in sync.  Yet, unless this routine is called with interrupts disabled, your tail pointer & queue size aren't adjusted as a single transaction.

(2) 
Furthermore, I'd guess that `gwCliQSize` is also adjusted in the interrupt (incremented in ISR, decremented in the application).  Another race condition.  To perform `gwCliQSize--`, behind the scenes you are probably reading from memory to a register, decrementing the register, then writing it back.  What happens if you read 5 from memory into R1, then an interrupt fires and increments it to 6, then you exit the ISR, and the register decrement and writeback (with a value of 4).

(3)
Lastly, it's possible (although not too likely) that `bTmpCh` or `bTestCh` are stored on the stack, and that your stack is getting corrupted / slammed by another task / interrupt / etc.  So when your assert fails, you're thinking it's R0 that is corrupted, but really it could be that the value moved into R0 before return, or the value moved out of R0 into a stack variable, is getting clobbered.

I've nattered on enough.  There are other possibilities but from what you've posted (and not posted) it's impossible to say for sure.

P.S.  If you've used a debugger and it's really & literally R0's value that is getting corrupted, not just the value of the character in the queue, that points to a problem in your scheduler / context switcher / ISR pre- or post-amble etc...

Answer (score 0):

here is the assembly code:
for the test():

```
0x00001308  E92D4010  STMDB     R13!,{R4,R14}
    37:     bTestCh = cliDequeue(); 
    38:          
0x0000130C  EB000207  BL        cliDequeue(0x00001B30)
0x00001310  E1A04000  MOV       R4,R0
    39:     if (bTestCh != 0) 
    40:     {  
0x00001314  E3540000  CMP       R4,#pTest(0x00000000)
0x00001318  0A000007  BEQ       0x0000133C
    41:         ASSERT(bTestCh == 'v'); 
0x0000131C  E1A00000  NOP       
0x00001320  E3540076  CMP       R4,#0x00000076
0x00001324  0A000001  BEQ       0x00001330
0x00001328  E1A00000  NOP       
0x0000132C  EAFFFFFE  B         0x0000132C
0x00001330  E1A00000  NOP       
    42:         uartPutChar(bTestCh); 
    43:     } 
0x00001334  E1A00004  MOV       R0,R4
0x00001338  EB00014A  BL        uartPutChar(0x00001868)
    44: } 
    45:  
    46: int main(void) 
0x0000133C  E8BD4010  LDMIA     R13!,{R4,R14}
0x00001340  E12FFF1E  BX        R14
```

for the cliDequeu(), BTW, gwCliQSize is defined as
UINT32 volatile  gwCliQSize;

```
0x00001B30  E59F00D4  LDR       R0,[PC,#0x00D4]
0x00001B34  E5900000  LDR       R0,[R0]
0x00001B38  E3500000  CMP       R0,#pTest(0x00000000)
0x00001B3C  1A000001  BNE       0x00001B48
    78:         return 0; 
    79:     } 
    80:      
    81:     bTmpCh = gabCliQ[gwCliQTail]; 
    82:     gwCliQTail++; 
    83:     gwCliQTail %= MAX_CLI_QUEUE_LEN; 
    84:     ASSERT(gwCliQSize > 0); 
    85:     gwCliQSize--; 
    86:  
    87:     //chCheck(bTmpCh); 
    88:          ASSERT(bTmpCh == 'v');   /* will not assert */ 
    89:     //uartPutChar(bTmpCh); 
    90:      
    91:     return bTmpCh; 
0x00001B40  E3A00000  MOV       R0,#pTest(0x00000000)
    92: } 
    93:  
    94:  
    95: void cliQInit(void) 
0x00001B44  E12FFF1E  BX        R14
    81:     bTmpCh = gabCliQ[gwCliQTail]; 
0x00001B48  E59F00C0  LDR       R0,[PC,#0x00C0]
0x00001B4C  E59F20C4  LDR       R2,[PC,#0x00C4]
0x00001B50  E5922000  LDR       R2,[R2]
0x00001B54  E7D01002  LDRB      R1,[R0,R2]
    82:     gwCliQTail++; 
0x00001B58  E59F00B8  LDR       R0,[PC,#0x00B8]
0x00001B5C  E5900000  LDR       R0,[R0]
0x00001B60  E2800001  ADD       R0,R0,#0x00000001
0x00001B64  E59F20AC  LDR       R2,[PC,#0x00AC]
0x00001B68  E5820000  STR       R0,[R2]
    83:     gwCliQTail %= MAX_CLI_QUEUE_LEN; 
0x00001B6C  E2820000  ADD       R0,R2,#pTest(0x00000000)
0x00001B70  E5900000  LDR       R0,[R0]
0x00001B74  E20000FF  AND       R0,R0,#0x000000FF
0x00001B78  E5820000  STR       R0,[R2]
    84:     ASSERT(gwCliQSize > 0); 
0x00001B7C  E1A00000  NOP       
0x00001B80  E59F0084  LDR       R0,[PC,#0x0084]
0x00001B84  E5900000  LDR       R0,[R0]
0x00001B88  E3500000  CMP       R0,#pTest(0x00000000)
0x00001B8C  1A000001  BNE       0x00001B98
0x00001B90  E1A00000  NOP       
0x00001B94  EAFFFFFE  B         0x00001B94
0x00001B98  E1A00000  NOP       
    85:     gwCliQSize--; 
    86:  
    87:     //chCheck(bTmpCh); 
0x00001B9C  E59F0068  LDR       R0,[PC,#0x0068]
0x00001BA0  E5900000  LDR       R0,[R0]
0x00001BA4  E2400001  SUB       R0,R0,#0x00000001
0x00001BA8  E59F205C  LDR       R2,[PC,#0x005C]
0x00001BAC  E5820000  STR       R0,[R2]
    88:          ASSERT(bTmpCh == 'v');   /* will not assert */ 
    89:     //uartPutChar(bTmpCh); 
    90:      
0x00001BB0  E1A00000  NOP       
0x00001BB4  E3510076  CMP       R1,#0x00000076
0x00001BB8  0A000001  BEQ       0x00001BC4
0x00001BBC  E1A00000  NOP       
0x00001BC0  EAFFFFFE  B         0x00001BC0
0x00001BC4  E1A00000  NOP       
    91:     return bTmpCh; 
    92: } 
    93:  
    94:  
    95: void cliQInit(void) 
0x00001BC8  E1A00001  MOV       R0,R1
0x00001BCC  EAFFFFDC  B         0x00001B44
```

for cliEnqueue:

```
void cliEnqueue(CHAR bC)
{
    if (gwCliQSize == MAX_CLI_QUEUE_LEN)
    {
        ASSERT(0);
    }

    gabCliQ[gwCliQHeader] = bC;
    gwCliQHeader++;
    gwCliQHeader %= MAX_CLI_QUEUE_LEN;
    gwCliQSize++;
}
```

assembly:

```
0x00001A5C  E59F11AC  LDR       R1,[PC,#0x01AC]
0x00001A60  E59F21AC  LDR       R2,[PC,#0x01AC]
0x00001A64  E5922000  LDR       R2,[R2]
0x00001A68  E7C10002  STRB      R0,[R1,R2]
    25:     gwCliQHeader++; 
0x00001A6C  E59F11A0  LDR       R1,[PC,#0x01A0]
0x00001A70  E5911000  LDR       R1,[R1]
0x00001A74  E2811001  ADD       R1,R1,#0x00000001
0x00001A78  E59F2194  LDR       R2,[PC,#0x0194]
0x00001A7C  E5821000  STR       R1,[R2]
    26:     gwCliQHeader %= MAX_CLI_QUEUE_LEN; 
0x00001A80  E2821000  ADD       R1,R2,#pTest(0x00000000)
0x00001A84  E5911000  LDR       R1,[R1]
0x00001A88  E20110FF  AND       R1,R1,#0x000000FF
0x00001A8C  E5821000  STR       R1,[R2]
    27:     gwCliQSize++; 
0x00001A90  E59F1174  LDR       R1,[PC,#0x0174]
0x00001A94  E5911000  LDR       R1,[R1]
0x00001A98  E2811001  ADD       R1,R1,#0x00000001
0x00001A9C  E59F2168  LDR       R2,[PC,#0x0168]
0x00001AA0  E5821000  STR       R1,[R2]
    28: } 
    29:  
    30:  
    31: static void chCheck(CHAR cTmpChar) 
    32: { 
0x00001AA4  E12FFF1E  BX        R14
```

0),1):  that gwCliQSize and the array are shared between ISR and main loop.

2) gwCliQSize is defined as volatile
3) from the assembly, bTestCh is R4 (moved from R0) and bTmpCh is R1 (moved to R0 before B)
4) I am using the J-LINK, but without J-LINK (run from flash), it still exists.

Comment: R4 and R0 are the same when it fails, so I think it is R0 corrupted, then bad value is moved to R4. at the other size, I think R1 is correct since  the ASSERT() in cliDequeue() is passed.